# Functionto create a DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a DF from another DF  using a function like this:

```
def create_df_region(df,region):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_reduced.index)
    df['Cons'] = df_reduced['ind_{region}'.format()].value
```

Problem is:  `ind_{}`  can assume values like `ind_s, ind_n, ind_no` and I want to pass these values when creating the DF because n means norh, s means south and so on.

then, to create the df:

```
df_south = create_df_region(df_reduced, s)
```

when s mean the south beacuse in the `df_reduced` i have columns `ind_s, ind_s...`

How can I do it as the way i am trying abive is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the newly created dataframe at the end of the function,
use `.values` instead of `.value` and use f-string for retrieving the source column name, as follows:

```
def create_df_region(df, region):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_reduced.index)
    df['Cons'] = df_reduced[f'ind_{region}'].values    # use .values instead of .value
    return df
```

Also, when you call the function, you need to pass a string `'s'` instead of the variable name `s` as follows:

```
df_south = create_df_region(df_reduced, 's')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `f'ind_{region}'` instead `.format()`:

```py
def create_df_region(df_reduced,region):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=df_reduced.index)
    df['Cons'] = df_reduced[f'ind_{region}'].value
```

*I've also changed the first parameter of the function from `df` to `df_reduced` to make sense.